# Postgres join with array type resulting in array column

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, join

I've seen similar questions posted on here, but none of the solutions I've found have seemed to give me the results I'm looking for.

So I have two tables:

Cards table has collectible cards with unique IDs and additional metadata (casting cost, etc.):

```
Cards
| id INTEGER | name TEXT | ... |
```

Prints table contains printing information for cards from Cards table (this is because the same card can be printed in different versions through different card sets):

```
Prints
| id INTEGER | card_id INTEGER | set TEXT | ... |
```

What I would like to do is to be able to query for a given card, but include all printings for said card within a single row response. I've been able to do that, somewhat, but instead if there are 6 printings for a card it will result in 6 rows, each row containing all the printing information as a string in JSON format.

The query I've been trying to use is the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(cards.id), cards.*, array_agg(printings.*) FROM cards
LEFT JOIN printings ON cards.id=printings.card_id
WHERE cards.name="C1" 
GROUP BY cards.id,printings.id ORDER BY cards.id;
```

This has resulted in output like (and the printing_information was just a string):

```
| id | name | ... |        printing_information            |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
| 1  | C1   | ... | { printInfo1, printInfo2, printInfo3 } |
```

What I would like to be able to do is join the prints with the cards such that the response would produce:

```
| id | name | ... |        printing_information            |
|  1 | C1   | ... | { print1Info, print2Info, print3Info } |
|  2 | C2   | ... | { print1Info, print2Info }             |
```

Is it worth doing all of this in a single query? I could achieve this with some minor post processing, but would that be as performant as it would require multiple queries and would not be that pretty since it could be for multiple cards and search for multiple ids seems messy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Note that `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to _all_ columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses will not change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b,c` is the same as `distinct a,(b),c` or `distinct a,b,(c)` or `distinct a,b,c`. Combined with `group by` it's even more useless

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Distinct was more of a last effort attempt for the night to see if it would only give me a single row instead of the 6 I was seeing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to aggregate the `prints` table first, then join to the `cards` table.

```
SELECT c.*, p.printing_information
FROM cards c
  LEFT JOIN (
    select pr.card_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(pr))  as printing_information
    from printings pr
    group by pr.card_id 
  ) p ON c.id = p.card_id
WHERE c.name = 'C1'
ORDER BY c.id;
```

`to_jsonb(pr)` converts the whole row from the `printings` table into a JSON value. This is then aggregated into a JSON array using `jsonb_agg()` for all printings of a card. If you want to remove some columns from the JSON, e.g. the `card_id` and 'id' columns from the JSON, you can use `to_jsonb(pr) - 'card_id' - 'id'`

Comment: I haven’t had time to try this out yet, but thanks for the response! Out of curiosity, is this an expensive query, in your opinion, to be performing often for search’s? Additionally, if there is a third table for pricing information that is relative to all printings, I feel like the fan out could become expensive. This is just a fun project for now, but having a performant codebase is part of the fun :)